# webdriver can not be resolved type

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Getting Webdriver can not be resolved typed error on

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
```

line while creating simple selenium java project. Below are the specifiction which is used

- java - 11
- selenium- 3.141.0
- eclipse ide- R2023-06

I have Tried adding selenium-server-standalone-3.141.0 jar file to the modulepath node also tried with classpath node but it didn't  worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your Selenium version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I was able to open a browser with the following lines.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
...
WebDriver dr = new ChromeDriver();
dr.get("https://google.com");
```

[image]